# Reuse <svg> <text> element <def> by passing in a text parameter to a <symbol>

Tags: svg

I have created a `<symbol>` to be reused many times in a document, and it works very well:

```
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,125,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <polygon id="hexagon" points="10,0 1.5,5 1.5,15 10,20 18.5,15 18.5,5" />
    <polygon id="checkmark" points="3.5,21 5,19 7.5,22 15,14 16,15.5 7.5,24.5"/>
    <symbol id="awsHex" viewBox="2 -2 300 300">
      <use href="#hexagon" transform="translate(0 0) scale(4)"
        fill="url(#grad1)" 
        stroke="#FFD600" 
        stroke-width="0.5" />
      <use href="#hexagon" transform="translate(30 14)" 
            fill="#00AA00" opacity="100%" />
      <use href="#checkmark" transform="translate(30,5.5)" fill="#FFF" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
```

It works well and I can use it multiple times like this:

```
  <use href="#awsHex" transform="translate(0 0)" /> 
  <use href="#awsHex" transform="translate(120 0)"/>  
  <use href="#awsHex" transform="translate(60 105)"/>  
  <use href="#awsHex" transform="translate(180 105)"/>
```

I would like to put a text element in the `<symbol>` so I can keep multiplying reuse while keeping the text inside the symbol.

```
<ref id="paramText" param="text-label">hexLabel</ref>
<symbol id="awsHex" viewBox="2 -2 300 300">
  <use href="#hexagon" transform="translate(0 0) scale(4)"
        fill="url(#grad1)" 
        stroke="#FFD600" 
        stroke-width="0.5" />
  <use href="#hexagon" transform="translate(30 14)" 
            fill="#00AA00" opacity="100%" />
  <use href="#checkmark" transform="translate(30,5.5)" fill="#FFF" />
  <text id="myLabel" x="40" y="50" font-family="Helvetica" 
            font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="10">
    <tref xlink:href="#paramText" />
    <param name="text-label" value="text-label" />
  </text>
</symbol>
```

That obviously doesn't work, which is why I'm here.

Is there no way to reuse a symbol with a text element by passing in and overriding the text content? It seems I can override any attributes, but not the content of the element?

Is there a workaround to overcome this difficulty of `svg`? It looks like they were working on this in the SVG standard but maybe it is not implemented yet? [SVG Parameters docs](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/param/master/SVGParamPrimer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Even if you could, symbols are not intended to be parameterised.  Symbols are for when you want to reuse the identical graphic multiple times.

You could use a symbol to represent the background of your text graphic, then just add a new `<text>` element each time for the text part.

Or you could use javascript to implement a custom element.

```
<thing text="whatever"/>
```

Your JS would look for every `<thing>` elements and replace it with a `<symbol>` element and a `<text>` element.

Comment: Does SVG have another element that can organize a scalable group of elements and can accept a parameter? I'm looking for something that can be resized as a symbol can be.

I will try a JS solution next. I think there are some libraries that provide parameterized composition, or just the vanilla solution you suggest.

Comment: No. Sorry.  It doesn't.

Comment: For ``<thing>`` inspiration, see [the ``<pie-chart>`` Web Component I wrote](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56), using (UnknownElement) ``<slice>``